# trying to install lxml on max osx leopard

Tags: python, django, unix, lxml

I have tried lots of different guides.. this one gets me the furthest..

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -lgcrypt -fPIC" STATIC_DEPS=true easy_install-2.6 lxml
```

however after installing all dependencies I get this error message over and over again:

```
    install-NRDNAB/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libxslt.m4 '/private/tmp/easy_install-NRDNAB/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/share/aclocal'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 xsltConf.sh '/private/tmp/easy_install-NRDNAB/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libxslt.pc libexslt.pc '/private/tmp/easy_install-NRDNAB/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig'
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxml2 2.7.8 and libxslt 1.1.26
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /private/tmp/easy_install-NRDNAB/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: -lgcrypt: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: -lgcrypt: linker input file unused because linking not done
powerpc-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: -lgcrypt: linker input file unused because linking not done
powerpc-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: -lgcrypt: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: -lgcrypt: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: -lgcrypt: linker input file unused because linking not done
ld: library not found for -lgcrypt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: library not found for -lgcrypt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: library not found for -lgcrypt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccZA43Kh.out (No such file or directory)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
sh-3.2#
```

Comment: may be you can try with super user and also try to install build-essential package...

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" easy_install lxml
```