# Error when installing Twisted using PIP

Tags: twisted, pip, scrapy, easy-install

4.11 and I'm trying to install Scrapy using either pip or easy_install.

It keeps failing for both, first it failed saying i didnt have gcc-4.0 available, then i used my install cd to install it. Now its popping up with other error(s).

Running setup.py install for Twisted, I receive the following errors in the beginning

```
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:21: error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:1:21: error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccXYV9xx.out
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:23: error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:1:23: error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//cctYFimU.out
building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c twisted/test/raiser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted/test/raiser.o
```

and ends with:

> lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccYXFDmd.out
>   error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

I'm new to this all and any help to solve this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Are you on OS X?

Try this:

`sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" pip install scrapy`

Related: [trying to install lxml on max osx leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341087/trying-to-install-lxml-on-max-osx-leopard)

Comment: It still gives me errors. I'm on Mac 10.4.11 and the errors i receive are like this:

raiser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-intel-2.7/twisted/test/raiser.o
    gcc-4.0: Unable to guess config name for arch x86_64

Why does it build 10.3-intel?!

Comment: I'm not an expert on 10.4, but guessing its a 32-bit distro try: `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" pip install scrapy`